# Using e-mail address as user name for SMTP and POP3

Tags: configuration, exim

I have a exim4 setup as SMTP. My user naming schema is to name all mail users for this server as m001, m002, m003, ... and then redirect to a real e-mail address with virtual domains.

> How can I allow my users to
>   authenticate with exim to send mail
>   using either their system user name
>   (m001) or the email address
>   (info@example.com)?

User login information for m001 are stored in linux system files (passwd, shadow). They are linked thru entries in a virtual address table for each domain that this server can serve:

```
# /etc/exim4/virtual/example.com
m001: info@example.com
m002: test@example.com
m003: john@mydomain.org
```

The same can be applied to qpopper ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about qpopper so I'll not be tackling that.

Regarding exim, the answer is almost definitely "yes".  I suspect you want to narrow down your question to get a better answer.  Here is how I currently read your implied question:

"How can I allow my users to authenticate with exim to send mail using either their system user name (m001) or the email address (info@example.com)?"

If that's the question and you want it answered, you need to provide the mechanism via which m001 and info@example.com are currently linked to each other, and where authentication information for these users is currently stored, and in what format (plaintext or encrypted, and how encrypted).